# inverse problem about scalar multiplication on elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a finite field $F_p$. Given $n$ be a positive integer and $Q$ be a point on $E$, assume that $Q=nP$, how can we find this $P$? We can assume that $n|p-1$. If $n$ is "small", I would imagine that it is possible using division polynomials. Is it a difficult problem if $n$ is large enough? How difficult is it?

Comment: You can recover $P$ by computing $(n^{-1} \bmod l)\cdot Q$, where $l$ is the order of $Q$.

Comment: Solving $Q=np$ for $n$ is the discrete logarithm problem and expensive. Solving for $P$ is cheap (assuming the order of the curve is known).

Comment: Why do you assume that $n$ divides $p-1$ ? Is there any specific reason for this condition, if so could you explain what it is ?

Comment: @SamuelNeves does it works on secp256k1 which is a koblitz curve?

Comment: Yes, it will work on any prime order curve.

Comment: @SamuelNeves would it be possible to have computer code in that case https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4852418/?

Answer (score 11):

As Samuel Neves described in the comments it is trivially possible to obtain $P$ from $Q=[n]P$, given $Q$ and the integer $n$.

Simply compute $k=n^{-1} \bmod \ell$, with $\ell=|E(\mathbb F_p)|$ being the order (= the number of points) of the curve. $\ell$ is usually known.

Then, to obtain the desired point $P$, calculate $P=[k]Q=[kn]P$ and you're done.

Comment: does it works on secp256k1 which is a koblitz curve?